Expo (React Native) app not receiving the context from the AuthProvider
I have this problem with my expo app I'm actually a beginner to mobile app development as a whole, I've tried everything i can, but nothing worked.
I'm using TypeScript btw.
AuthContext.tsx:
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  ReactNode,
} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native-paper";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

type AuthContextType = {
  onRegister: (username: string, password: string) => Promise<any>;
  onLogin: (username: string, password: string) => Promise<any>;
  onLogout: () => Promise<void>;
  authState: AuthStateType;
  authData: AuthDataType;
};

type AuthStateType = {
  token: string | null;
  authenticated: boolean;
};

type AuthDataType = {
  id: number | null;
  username: string | null;
  iat: number | null;
  exp: number | null;
};

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType | undefined>(undefined);

const TOKEN_KEY = "authToken";
const API_URL = "https://anonytext-backend.vercel.app/api";

const useAuth = (): AuthContextType => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider");
  }
  return context;
};

type AuthProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState<AuthStateType>({
    token: null,
    authenticated: false,
  });
  const [authData, setAuthData] = useState<AuthDataType>({
    id: null,
    username: null,
    iat: null,
    exp: null,
  });

  const register = async (username: string, password: string): Promise<any> => {
    try {
      return await axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/register`, {
        username,
        password,
      });
    } catch (e: any) {
      return {
        error: true,
        message: e.response?.data?.message || "An error occurred",
      };
    }
  };

  const login = async (username: string, password: string): Promise<any> => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, {
        username,
        password,
      });
      setAuthState({ token: result.data.access, authenticated: true });
      axios.defaults.headers.common[
        "Authorization"
      ] = `Bearer ${result.data.access}`;
      await SecureStore.setItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY, result.data.access);

      return result;
    } catch (e: any) {
      return {
        error: true,
        message: e.response?.data?.message || "An error occurred",
      };
    }
  };

  const logout = async (): Promise<void> => {
    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY);
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "";
    setAuthState({ token: null, authenticated: false });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadToken = async () => {
      const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY);

      if (token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        setAuthState({ token, authenticated: true });
        setAuthData(jwtDecode(token));
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };

    loadToken();
  }, []);

  const contextData: AuthContextType = {
    onRegister: register,
    onLogin: login,
    onLogout: logout,
    authState,
    authData,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>
      {!loading ? children : <ActivityIndicator size={20} />}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AuthProvider, useAuth };

Which looks pretty solid to me and should be working, but i keep getting
(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: Error: useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider

This error is located at:
    in RootLayout
    in Unknown (created by Route())
    in Suspense (created by Route())
    in Route (created by Route())
    in Route() (created by ContextNavigator)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by wrapper)
    in wrapper (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ThemeProvider
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorOverlay (created by withDevTools(ErrorOverlay))
    in withDevTools(ErrorOverlay)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)

According to this message, the useAuth hook is supposed to be used in a child element wrapped with the AuthProvider Context, which is exactly what i did here:
App.tsx:
import React from "react";
import { AuthProvider } from "@/context/AuthContext";
import RootLayout from "./app/_layout";
import { NotifierWrapper } from "react-native-notifier";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

// Wrap the entire app with AuthProvider
export default function App() {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <NotifierWrapper>
        <AuthProvider>
          <RootLayout />
        </AuthProvider>
      </NotifierWrapper>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

And the ./app/_layout.tsx:
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { Slot, Redirect } from "expo-router";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useAuth } from "@/context/AuthContext";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native-paper";

// Prevent the splash screen from hiding until the font is loaded
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const { authState } = useAuth(); // Directly access authState from context

  console.log("Auth Context State:", authState);

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    FontAwesome6Pro: require("../assets/fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf"),
    FontAwesome6ProLight: require("../assets/fonts/fa-light-300.ttf"),
    FontAwesome6ProSolid: require("../assets/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf"),
  });

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null; // Keep splash screen visible while loading fonts
  }

  // If authState is undefined, don't attempt to render protected routes yet
  if (authState === undefined) {
    return <ActivityIndicator size={20} />; // Show loading indicator if auth state is undefined
  }

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      {authState.authenticated ? <Slot /> : <Redirect href="/login" />}
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

Which should also work cause i wrapped the RootLayout with the AuthProvider.
Is there something i did wrong or there's a step i missed?
